# Extract values from repeated columns in an array with BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Each array consists of information about which list (*internal_list_id*) does a certain contact belong to (*vid*).

I'm trying to include all *internal_list_id* (separated by comma) in one column grouped by *vid*.

The end data should like something like:

```
ContactID | ListMembership:
3291601     1058,1060
```

I've tried with the below code but it returns information about the first object only:

```
SELECT list_memberships[offset(1)].vid ContactId, list_memberships[offset(1)].internal_list_id ListMembership FROM hs.contacts as c
```

[image]

The below results is achieved via:

```
SELECT list_memberships FROM hs.contacts as c
```

[image]

P.S. If you have any suggestions for better a title please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Another thing to note is that each array has a different length.

Comment: can you provide example of input data and respective expected result - please provide as a text (not as an image)

Answer (score -1):

Use `STRING_AGG(x) FROM UNNEST(array)`, like in:

```sql
WITH data AS (
  SELECT visitStartTime, hits[OFFSET(0)].product
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801` 
  LIMIT 100
)


SELECT visitStartTime, (
  SELECT STRING_AGG(FORMAT('$%i', localProductPrice), ', ') 
  FROM UNNEST(product)
) aggregated
FROM data
```